# Do I have to worry about a Dynamic firing even when the value does not change?

Tags: haskell, reflex-dom

Using `reflex-dom` I found myself writing the following code:

```hs
dynShowNumbers <- holdDyn False $ catMaybes $ updated dynMaybeShowNumbers
```

where `dynMaybeShowNumbers :: Dynamic t (Maybe Bool)` fires, whenever a key is pressed or released, but it only has a value unequal to `Nothing`, when one of two specific keys change status (i.e. pressed or not-pressed). It fires `Just False` when one of the two keys is being released.

The reason is that I show a virtual keyboard that generally depends on any event of a key being pressed or released. For `dynMaybeShowNumbers`, I simply filter out two relevant keys that need to be hold down to show the virtual numpad.

I could easily write simpler code where `dynShowNumbers :: Dynamic t Bool` does not rely on the `Dynamic t (Maybe Bool)` as above.

However:

In that case, whenever any key is pressed I get my `dynShowNumbers` firing:

```
False---False---False------False--True---True----False----False----...
```

Whereas the above code would result in

```
False-----------------------------True-----------False-------------...
```

for the same input.

I feel, I need the above line to avoid dynamic re-rendering of my virtual keyboard--even when nothing changes.

---

But is the line above good practice? Is there an efficient function for this in the library (can't find it)? It's similar to the task of removing duplicates from a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options! In [`Reflex.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.8.2.0/docs/src/Reflex.Dynamic.html), you can use these `hold` variants:

```hs
-- | Create a new 'Dynamic' that only signals changes if the values actually
-- changed.
holdUniqDyn :: (Reflex t, MonadHold t m, MonadFix m, Eq a) => Dynamic t a -> m (Dynamic t a)

-- | Create a new 'Dynamic' that changes only when the underlying 'Dynamic'
-- changes and the given function returns 'False' when given both the old and
-- the new values.
holdUniqDynBy :: (Reflex t, MonadHold t m, MonadFix m) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> Dynamic t a -> m (Dynamic t a)
```

There seems to be a more principled, type-based approach in [`Reflex.Dynamic.Uniq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.8.2.0/docs/Reflex-Dynamic-Uniq.html). That whole module is focused on such situations.